# How to respond to late accepted answers that are duplicates of earlier ones?

Tags: discussion

I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29234827/html-page-doesnt-display/29345907#29345907), which had a bunch of correct answers on the same day the question was asked. Six days later, another answer pops out, saying basically the same thing in different words as the most upvoted answer. One minute later, the asker comments saying that resolved his problem and accepts it.

I think it's really strange, I'm wondering if that's not some sort of sock puppeting or maybe the answerer is a friend of the asker? Anyways, I wrote a comment, but I'm wondering if it's enough. I could downvote, but I don't see what it would change. Should there be something else to be done in these situations? Or I'm just making a big deal out of nothing and should just go on with my day?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're definitely right to be suspicious of scenarios like you described. Often (but not always) it's a sign of one or more abusive behaviours.

In this instance I've investigated and taken appropriate actions. In the general case you can flag -> other and describe what you saw and why it made you suspicious. The more detail you give the easier it is for us to investigate.

I wouldn't do more than flag and maybe down vote. If you comment and you're wrong it's noise at best, if you're right then the end result may well be grief and arguments coming your way.